# Не удается сообразить о типе переменной

Tags: java

Есть библиотека: https://github.com/sromku/polygon-contains-point

В ней пару примеров, где вертексы добавляются без всяких циклов. 
У меня же цикл, делаю так:

```
Polygon polygon = Polygon.Builder();

for (p = 0; p < pos.length; p++) {
    polygon.addVertex(new Point(Float.parseFloat(pos[p][0]), Float.parseFloat(pos[p][1])));             
}

polygon.build();
```

Всё это дело не работает и вываливается с ошибкой:

```
[javac]   required: Polygon
[javac]   found:    Builder
```

Меняя переменной `polygon` тип на `Builder`, вываливается ошибка, что вообще символ не найден.

Как тут быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказывается, что так:

```
Polygon.Builder polygon;
```